# Mass delete Drupal Commerce Coupons

Tags: commerce

I have used Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2 + Commerce Coupons (fixed, %) + Coupons Batch create to create  coupons. Now, is there any way to remove all coupons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below should do the trick. If you have [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) installed, just open the `devel/php` page and execute this:

```
// Get all coupons on the site.
$coupons = db_select('commerce_coupon', 'c')
  ->fields('c', array('coupon_id'))
  ->execute();

// We will store here all coupon IDs, so we can delete them at once.
$coupon_ids = array();
foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
  $coupon_ids[] = $coupon->coupon_id;
}

commerce_coupon_delete_multiple($coupon_ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to create a listing in Views and delete from the UI if you need to perform this operation often

Comment: That was the solution I was thinking about (I don't have much experience with VBO). I do not need it often, as it seems, it's just for debugging/developping, so the code solution suits me bette in this case.